# Spring Boot security allow requests from given IP address

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-rest

We have following security configure code,

```java
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/").and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

     GET /api/users
        POST /api/users
        GET /api/users/{userId}
```

We need to restrict below requests (not for all requests) in Spring Boot application and allow these requests only on given `ipaddress (multiple ipaddress)` in properties.

Answer (score 4):

Try with below configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/users/**").hasIpAddress("127.0.0.1")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/").and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your  post, here we need to configure multiple ipaddress

Comment: I just tried like below, seems this working.
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/users/**").access("hasIpAddress('10.00.07.9') or hasIpAddress('10.00.00.60')")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/").and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }